# Determine is a solution is basic in linear system.

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

We know that the maximum number of basic solution of a linear system is given by nCm where n is number of unknowns and m is the rank of coefficient matrix and also of augmented matrix.
By setting (n-m) variables equal to zero we obtain a basic solution. But if the question gives a solution and asks to check if the solution is basic then how should I approach?
Finding all the nCm basic solution and checking can be very lengthy procedure.

Comment: What exactly is a “basic solution?”

Comment: There are two facts you can use: (1) the number of basic and non-basic variables is known in advance, (2) any variable not at its bound is basic. There still may be some ambiguity left (this is the result of degeneracy).

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2751676/recover-linear-programming-basis